# Send jQuery array to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending an array object via ajax and C # MVC can not understand. 
I've tried several ways and does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I already have and without JSON.stringify, and not work. Variable `teste01` receives null.

Class of object:

```
public class Teste
{
    public int dataid {get;set;}
    public string datapackage { get; set;}
    public int packageid {get;set;}
}
```

Contoller:

```
[HandleError]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[Authorize]
public JsonResult ListaGenerica(DataTables param, string aController, Teste[] teste01, bool porID = false, string regra = "", int filtroID = 0, string tipo = "")
```

JQuery functions:

```
function Controller()
{
    return "EmpresaCarga";
}

function Dados()
{
    var localproducts = [];

    localproducts.push({
            'dataid' : 1, 
            'datapackage' : 'test', 
            'packageid' : 3
        });

    localproducts.push({
            'dataid' : 2, 
            'datapackage' : 'test 01', 
            'packageid' : 4
        });

    return localproducts;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var oTable = $('#listagem').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("ListaGenerica", "Ajax")',
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {            
        aoData.push( { "name": "filtroID", "value": $("#ClienteID").find('option:selected').val() } );
        aoData.push( { "name": "aController", "value": Controller() } );
        aoData.push( { "name": "teste01", "value": Dados() } );
    },
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "Carga", "sTitle": "Carga" },
            { "mDataProp": "DtCarga", "sTitle": "DtCarga", "mRender": function (data, type, full) { return dtConvFromJSON(data); } },       
            { "mDataProp": "Empresa", "sTitle": "Empresa" },
            { "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "mRender": function (data, type, row) { return '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/Produto/Detalhar/' + row.EmpresaCargaID + '" title="Clique para abrir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>';}}
        ],
    });
```

Query Strings Parameters

```
sEcho:2
.
.
.
filtroID:
aController:EmpresaCarga
aController:EmpresaCarga
teste01:[{"dataid":1,"datapackage":"test","packageid":3},{"dataid":2,"datapackage":"test 01","packageid":4}]
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly? Are you seeing an error on the page? Is nothing happening at all? Is control ever reaching your controller action?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker variable teste01, receives null.

Comment: Does the `ModelState` contain any errors?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker switching to `List<Teste> teste01`. `ModelState` Return erro: {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'FlexGestor.Controllers.AjaxController+Teste' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}

Comment: I think this is because DataTables is issuing a GET request and ASP.NET MVC does not deserialize JSON in this case. You could model bind to a string and manually deserialize the JSON in your controller action.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Have any examples of how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, this is probably because ASP.NET MVC isn't deserializing the JSON part of the query string into an object for you. You can either change the parameter to a `string` and deserialize yourself (this example uses JSON.NET):

```
public JsonResult ListaGenerica(string param, /* etc */)
{
    DataTables dataTables = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTables>(param);
}
```

Or you could use a `POST` instead from the `DataTables` end:

```
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
  oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
    "dataType": 'json',
    "type": "POST",
    "url": sSource,
    "data": aoData,
    "success": fnCallback
  });
}
```

Lots more information on the [documentation page](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) for making server-side requests.